# The global.game_width not set before reading it

Tags: dialog, game-maker-studio-2

```
global variable name 'game_width' index (100009) not set before reading it.
at gml_Object_objTextbox_Create_0 (line 16) port_x = (global.game_width  
- box_width - port_width) * 0.5
```

[image: The error Picture]

I created in Game global.game_height and width, but it doesn't work. What am I supposed to do?

[image: The error picture 2]

Comment: Looks like `objtextbox` is created earlier than the `game` object, that way it cannot find the `global.game_width` before it's initialised. Not sure how that's possible to change though, as you're running it already later than the `game` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I know what I have wrong and rewrote it and it works

Comment: Looks like I've understanded the problem now, and decided to make my comment an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `objtextbox` object is created earlier than the `game` object. 

And because the `game` object creates the variable, it cannot find the `global.game_width` before it's initialised.

Inside the Text Layer Properties on the left sidebar, you'll see all the objects that are loading inside the room. The `game` object is not shown there, so you've to place the `game` object inside the room (and change the order they're loaded first) to let it work.

I'm not sure if this still applies as you've already rewrote your code, but that's something to remember for the next time.